# Version difference between variouis Apache tomcat server versions causes any problem?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, version

I am not able to find "Application Server Apache Tomcat 6.0.18" i need this for ubuntu. Can any one help me with knowing the difference between this version and available version i.e "Application Server Apache Tomcat 6.0.32" ..
Is it safe to use the advance version when in project documentation it is mentioned that earlier version is required ?

Comment: Belongs on http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

In `6.0.32`, `6` is the major release number, `0` is the minor release number, `32` is the patch number.

And since this is a patch version and there are no new features/major changes, it is safe to use it in production.

Comment: Thanks Yasir for your quick response.